# sample from the base of the array elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array like `prods[[1,2] [3,4]]`, where the first elements(1,3) is a product_id, and the second (2,4) - it's quantity. I need to list all the products and their quantities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the array:

```
[[1,2],[3,4]].each { |product_id,qty|
  puts "#{product_id} => #{qty}"
}
```

Output:

```
1 => 2
3 => 4
```